# Xcode not in the Applications folder

Tags: xcode

I have installed xcode on my mac but I am annoyed that I have use Finder to track down the executable every time I want to run it (or User Interface Builder).  I have read that it is supposed to show up in the Applications folder under Development but there is no such folder.  Is there any way I can get xcode and its associated applications to appear in the Applications folder so its more convenient to use?

Comment: Why not just add it to the dock? That'll be most convenient,no?

Comment: Yep, that will do it.  I am new to using Mac's and expected that the Applications folder was something similar to Windows start menu.  That doesn't appear to be the case though.  There was an answer that has since been deleted that cleared that up.  Now I have both xcode and interface builder on the dock.  So its all good.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out why you would assume that a folder was similar to the Start menu in Windows. It's really just a folder on both platforms. You could however drag the Applications folder to your dock, and then you should be able to navigate through it hierarchically, much like the Start menu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, open the `/Developer` directory in Finder and right click on the `Applications` folder. Choose the **'Make alias'** option. An alias is created named `Applications alias`. Change the aliased folder's name to the one that most fits to you e.g. "XCode". Now, copy this alias into your `/Applications` directory. There you are.

Comment: After installing Xcode 9, there is no /Developer directory at the root of my MacBook Pro file system.

Comment: @PeteAlvin Sorry I can't help. This used to work for previous versions of Xcode, but since then I'm not using a MacOS any more.

Answer (score 8):

We can drag/paste the Xcode.app directly into Applications folder

Comment: How? // please explain complete procedure.

Comment: Most macOS applications downloaded from outside the store come inside a DMG file. Double-click the DMG file to open it, and you’ll see a Finder window. Often these will include the application itself, some form of an arrow, and a shortcut to the Applications folder. Simply drag the application’s icon to your Applications folder and you’re done.

Comment: Or you can copy/move the .app from the source directory and paste inside /Users/<user_name>/Applications directory